# How to make a change to all objects of type text field in the app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to easily make a change in all objects of a certain type inside my app? 
For example, change the font/color of all UILabels or to apply the `setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:` function on all the `UILabels`.

Comment: You can try out method swizzling. Where you can swizzle the original selectors or methods of a type to your custom selector or method. Read more about it here - http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/ . HTH :)

Comment: You can customise the appearance of a whole class of UIKit controls using  UIAppearance https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html

Comment: you can use `Subclass` option to set specific property of each `UILabel` in your project. read more details about [`subclassing` here](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/subclassing/)

Answer (score 0):

You can change  width ,color,size of `textfield` or any objects using below code.

```
 for(UITextField *txt in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if([txt isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            //here do your work
            txt.frame=CGRectMake(0, 50, 100, 100);//set size,color anything your want.
        }
    }
```

make class of object which you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following `UIView` category:

**UIView+MakeChange.h**

```
@import UIKit;

@interface UIView (MakeChange)
    +(void)makeChangeInView:(UIView*)superview 
                  withBlock:(void(^)(__kindof UIView* view))block;
@end
```

**UIView+MakeChange.m**

```
#import "UIView+MakeChange.h"

@implementation UIView (MakeChange)

+(void)makeChangeInView:(UIView*)superview 
              withBlock:(void(^)(__kindof UIView* view))block 
{
    if(!block || !superview) return;

    for(UIView* subview in superview.subviews) 
    {
        // Make changes to all subviews recursively
        [self makeChangeInView:subview withBlock:block];

        if([subview isKindOfClass:self.class])
            block(subview);
    }
}

@end
```

You can change the font/color of every currently displayed `UILabel` using this code:

```
[UILabel makeChangeInView:[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject]
                withBlock:^(UILabel* label) {
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0]];
}];
```

- Obviously, the same category can be used for any UIView subclass as well (`UITextField`, `UIButton`, etc.)
- Use it with caution, especially if your UI is complex - all the work is done on UI thread (no other easy choice), and you don't want to block it for too long... For the same reason, try to avoid using it for the main application window (as in my example).